# How to setup a Webmail inside Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, blogs, webmail

i am trying to setup a webmail login page into wordpress nevertheless i havent found a way to do it, i've admit i'm wordpress rookie so i might be thinking things wrong, do you have any advice how to proceed?

Is there any plugin that enables a webmail login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that the easiest way to do this would be to write your own plugin. It's very easy to make a plugin that adds an optiosn page and then edit the options page to reflect the webmail login.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://www.matrich.net/wordpress-plugins/wp-cpanel-email-login-plugin.htm